# How to use "selenium-webdriver-xpath" to get the text value from <td>?

Tags: ruby, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Find the below `html` code:

```
<table id="supplier_list_data" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" class="data">
   <tr class="rowLight">
      <td class="extraWidthSmall">
         <a href="/aems/do.list">  Cdata </a>
      </td>
      <td class="extraWidthSmall">
         <a href="/aem/do.list">  xyz </a>
      </td>
      <td class="extraWidthSmall">
         <a href="/bem/do.list">  ppm </a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now using `xpath` how to get the value `xyz` (means always the second `"<td>"`) . Give me an idea please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `//tr/td[2]/data()`.

`//tr/td` selects all `<td/>` elements, `[2]` the second result inside each `<tr/>` and `data()` returns their contents.

Comment: so data() would give the fule <a>..</a> elements, but I need the content `xyz`. So hope `driver.find_element(:xpath,"//tr/td[2]/a")` will get the text out right? if I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: I don't know about the stuff around the XPath query, but it looks fine. Without `data()` you would get the full elements, with it you will only get the contents. Just try yourself, for visual feedback have a look at [BaseX GUI](http://www.basex.org) which is great for learning and testing XQuery.